# Is there an expression close to "grabbing for crumbs"?

Tags: phrase-requests, idioms, idiom-requests

Two people are having a debate and one tries to make a point that seems like they are desperately trying to pedantically nitpick a very small thing in order to disprove the others argument. Is there an expression for this?

Here's an example: "Most health institutions have concluded that there are health risks in smoking. However just the other day one researcher was caught modifying data in attempt to overplay the risks and they were later found to be paid by a major healthcare insurer. This is further evidence that there are no health risks in smoking."

Comment: If you refer to an argument based on technical "jargon", consider ["argument by gibberish"](https://www.logicallyfallacious.com/tools/lp/Bo/LogicalFallacies/47/Argument-by-Gibberish)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are **clutching at straws**:

"Out of desperation, the act of reaching or stretching for a solution, no matter how irrational or inconsequential.[Urban Dictionary](http://urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=clutching%20at%20straws)

Comment: Must be a regional thing- I've only ever heard *grasping* at straws.  Also, allow me to suggest a more authoritative reference: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/grasping+at+straws

Comment: *clutching* is more common in the UK, or at least the bits of it I know (@cobaltduck)

Comment: @cobaltduck - I don't think it matters much whether you clutch or grab.  Either one should be understandable on either side of the Atlantic. // Good answer!